# Return multiple duplicate Keys in PHP to json AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, get

Pretty comfortable with PHP but fighting with jQuery.
I have a bootstrap modal that is used for editing a project and I'm using AJAX to populate the fields when an edit button is clicked. This works great but a project can be in multiple departments (checkboxes in the modal)

This is how I'm populating the modal:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'project_tasks.php?task=select_project&pjct_id=' + id,
method: 'GET',
dataType: 'json'
}).success(function(response) {
// Populate the form fields with the data returned from server
$('#edit_project')
    .find('[name="project_id"]').val(response.project_id).end()
    .find('[name="project_title"]').val(response.project_title).end()
    .find('[name="project_bgcolor"]').val(response.project_bgcolor).end()
    .find('[name="project_desc"]').val(response.project_desc).end()
    .find(':checkbox[name^="department"]').each(function () {
    if($(this).val() ==  response.dpmt_id) {
        console.log("depart: " + response.dpmt_id);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

And the PHP is (not escaping yet but will do):

```
    $pjct_id = $_GET['pjct_id'];
    $pjct = Projects::find_by_id($pjct_id);

    $dpmts = Projects_departments::find_all_by_pjct_id($pjct_id);
    foreach ($dpmts as $dpmt) {
        $response_array['dpmt'] = $dpmt->department_id;
    }
    $response_array['project_id'] .= $pjct->id;
    $response_array['project_title'] .= $pjct->project_title;
    $response_array['project_bgcolor'] .= $pjct->project_bgcolor;
    $response_array['project_desc'] .= $pjct->project_desc;
    echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Obviously I know that 'dpmt' is being overwritten each time so I only get the json `dpmt : 1` rather than each departments ID but I would like to achieve something like `dpmt: 1, dpmt: 2, dpmt: 3` and then loop through that to tick the checkbox.

Hopefully I've explained myself well enough (The wife is rushing me out)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP: return an array of ids instead of an integer/string.

```
...
foreach ($dpmts as $dpmt) {
    $response_array['dpmt'][] = $dpmt->department_id;
}
...
```

The Javascript: use a combined selector, so you don't have to loop every checkbox. Use the loop only on the dpmt_ids returned by the PHP.

```
$('#edit_project')
    .find('[name="project_id"]').val(response.project_id).end()
    .find('[name="project_title"]').val(response.project_title).end()
    .find('[name="project_bgcolor"]').val(response.project_bgcolor).end()
    .find('[name="project_desc"]').val(response.project_desc).end()
;
for (i=0; i< response.dpmt_id.length; ++i) {
     $('#edit_project').find(':checkbox[name="department[]"][value="'+response.dpmt_id[i]+'"]').prop('checked',true);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I did need to change find(':checkbox[name="department" to find(':checkbox[name="department[]"

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback. Changed it in the answer so it is more clear to anyone else.